# Approximating Lebesgue measurable sets by dyadic intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I know something about bounded sets which are the union of dyadic intervals, and I want to extend to bounded Lebesgue measurable sets. Is there a way of approximating the latter by the former that controls, say, the measure of the symmetric difference?